# How to block incoming calls when recording audio or video?

Tags: java, android

I am developing an application.In this application we are gonna provide video and audio capturing.But the problem is when audio or video is being recorded, if i get a call then video pauses. Is there any way to block incoming calls when video being recorded?

Comment: show us some efforts, show us what you have tried, learn to use google

Comment: There should be.

Comment: @Aksahy Katariya. I have enough skills.

Answer (score 0):

Create a BlockCallReceiver which extends the BroadcastReceiver to block the incoming calls. 
Follow the [link](http://androidforbegineers.blogspot.in/2013/07/block-incoming-calls-android.html) for more details.